# Can my deleted question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises, specific-question, deleted-questions

A question [Is the force exerted on the chair transferred to the rope that is pulled on?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348145/)  I asked some time ago was deleted because it did not meet the standard of the Physics Stack Exchange website. I decided to revisit the question and modify it.

Could this question be reopened?

Comment: I undeleted your question, by the way, since there's activity on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good of you to ask about this.

Your question might be suitable for reopening, but here's why I'm a bit wary about that. Our [policy on homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) says that you need to narrow down the problem to the specific concept that is giving you trouble and ask about that. By showing your work, you've done a very good job of narrowing down the problem to the part that you get stuck on, but then you made a very unfortunate choice of wording:

> I do not know how to proceed from this point.

This phrase is, in some sense, the death knell of homework-like questions on this site. We see so many people present a homework problem and show a few steps of what they've done, but the *only* thing they actually ask is "what do I do next?" or "I'm not sure where to go from here" or something similar. We don't handle those kinds of questions. Those are people simply looking for homework help, which is not what we do here. This has become so common that a lot of people will see a phrase like that and instinctively hit the "close" button. (Well, it's not technically a button, but effectively it works that way.)

In your case, though, there's more to your question. You also have this:

> How is the 100 lbs downwards force impacting the free body diagram of the entire system?

That's much closer to being a specific conceptual question. Admittedly I'm not quite sure what to make of it, since I'm not sure what you mean by a "force impacting the free body diagram of the entire system", but that's probably a minor wording issue that can get clarified with a small edit. (Chat will be good for that.)

So in summary, I think your question might be pretty close to good but I would like to see the phrase "I do not know how to proceed from this point" removed, which will help make it more explicitly clear to everyone that you're asking a conceptual question about how a force affects a free body diagram (or whatever) and *not* asking for further directions on how to solve the problem. Ordinarily I would probably just make that edit myself because it's presumably pretty minor, but since I'm already writing a meta post, I figured I would just mention it here so you can make the edit if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive feedback. I have edited my question according to the suggestion you gave here.

Comment: My question is still closed. What can I do to get it reopened?

Comment: @a_sid Usually, when an on-hold/closed post is edited, it kicks off an automatic review process by which people will look at the question and vote on whether it deserves to be reopened. That didn't happen in this case, probably because your question was old or because it had been deleted or because it already went through this review process once; I forget the criteria. Anyway, in general, the thing to do about this is wait a day or two and then flag it like you did. I'll reopen the question.